# Absolute path or permalink for images on markdown (Hugo)

Tags: hugo

I'm building a website where I render the content from the latest blog post on the home page. The problem is that, since images have a relative path by default, they are not working.

The image URL is './image.png' on the blog post page, which works, but also on my home page. On my home page I need it to be '.blog-post/image.png' or even the absolute path, but the Permalink variable doesn't work inside the figure shortcode I'm using (or at least I don't know how to use it):
`{{< figure src="./image.png" caption="Imagem caption" >}}`

Comment: Not sure what your setup is. If you can provide a repo it would help greatly in understanding what you want to achieve or the error you're encountering.

Basically, the figure shortcode should just work. The "./filename.ext" notation you used should generate `https://example.com/blog/blog-post/image.png`.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest giving the image it's absolute path.
Or, use image processing to render our your paths for you, so their is just "no issue"
i.e. {{(resources.GetMatch "imagenamehere.png").Permalink}}
Something like that.

Comment: But can I do that inside the figure shortcode?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. 
Can you put hugo code into a shortcode... Yes... that IS what a shortcode is. 
If you mean, can you use the stock shortcode to do that. No.

Comment: I wanted to use the absolute path inside hugo's figure shortcode. Couldn't find a way of doing that.
I'm solving the issue for now by moving the images to the static folder. Not ideal.

Comment: You need to write your own shortcode.